# The most optimal way to UPDATE one field in thousands of MySQL rows?

Tags: php, mysql

So let's say I need to change MySQL field named "active" from 0 to 1 or whatever, but I need to do that for hundreds or even thousands of rows. I have a PHP array with row IDs.

What's the best way to do it?
"The best" is defined as the most optimal in terms of time needed to execute it and CPU usage I guess?

I thought of two ways.

1. doing a foreach loop on that PHP array with
   `UPDATE table SET active = 1 WHERE id = ?`
   so I'll execute thousands of MySQL queries, or whatever is the number of elements in array that I have
2. `UPDATE table SET active = 1 WHERE id IN (?,?,?,.....)`
3. Any better solution?

Comment: Number 2 makes sense.

Comment: I think 2 would take more resources as it needs to evaluate each `in` value.

Comment: @user3783243 what makes you say that?  I doubt it would take more than sending hundreds of individual separate queries.

Comment: @ADyson In my experience the #1 performs better. Connection timeout is shorter, locks are shorter. Timewise it likely is longer but resource wise should be less intense

Comment: @user3783243 it doesn't if id is indexed.

Comment: Both #1 and #2 are fine. A definite answer cannot be given, because we require more information. See this article: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153869/which-is-faster-multiple-update-queries-in-a-cursor-loop-or-a-single-query

Of course, id should be indexed, but I assume that for the moment.

You may also have your max packet size configuration in mind if you are really speaking of (ten-?)thousands of records with big id count.

Personally, at first, I would go for where-in.

Answer (score 0):

- If you need to update  all the rows in table then you don't need where clause and simple update query should do the trick
- If you need to do it on certain data try to find the another column which meets the criteria of updating and set the where clause to that criteria, may be where active=0 can work
- if you are not able to find the criteria other than ids then if the data is huge like thousands of records, then 1st paginate the data and create a batch of 1000, create string of ids foreach and pass it to id IN (ids) as last resort.